# Pandas series with dictionary to string or json format

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas series containing values of type `dict`. I have used `ast.literal_eval` to turn `string` or `json` into `dict`.

I am looking to do the reverse now. How do I turn `dict` into `string`? Sample data for reference:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}] })
```

Comment: `df['d'] = df['d'].str`?

Comment: map the `str` constructor or `repr`.  `df.applymap(str)`

Comment: In this example: `df['d_str'] = df['d'].astype(str)`

Comment: @Barmar the `.str` is an accessor object that points to a bunch of string related methods.  It won't turn the elements to strings.

Comment: `df['d'].to_numpy(dtype='str').tolist()` a list of strings.

Comment: What is your expected output from the above dataframe?

Comment: `df['d'].to_json(orient='records')` ??